# Javascript - Assign (not clone) a large object to a new variable to reduce its name

Tags: javascript, object, clone, use-strict

I want to assign a large object to a new variable to reduce its name, but I have an error : `"realEstateProjectFundReuse" is read-only`

```
const realEstateProjectFundReuse = this.project.realEstateProjectMotivation.realEstateProjectFundReuse
    realEstateProjectFundReuse = omit(realEstateProjectFundReuse, [this.fundReuseTypeChoose(), 'description'])
```

But this syntax works

```
const realEstateProjectFundReuse = this.project.realEstateProjectMotivation.realEstateProjectFundReuse
this.project.realEstateProjectMotivation.realEstateProjectFundReuse = omit(realEstateProjectFundReuse, [this.fundReuseTypeChoose(), 'description'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the keyword `const` you create a constant, which cannot get assigned another value (like in your second line).

But even if you would use `let` to define a variable, setting it to a new value would not change the original object. The reason therefore is that `omit` creates a new object. `realEstateProjectFundReuse` would then point to the newly created object while `this.project.realEstateProjectMotivation.realEstateProjectFundReuse` still points to the old one.

One option would be the following:

```
const projectMotivation = this.project.realEstateProjectMotivation;
projectMotivation.realEstateProjectFundReuse = omit(projectMotivation.realEstateProjectFundReuse, [this.fundReuseTypeChoose(), 'description'])
```